# morris.js error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, morris.js

I'm getting an error when I try to use [morris.js](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/index.html) in my Ruby on Rails project.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

This is my file

```
= content_tag :div, "", id: "weights_chart", data: {weights: @weights}
:javascript
   new Morris.Line({
       element: 'weights_chart',
       data: $('#weights_chart').data('weights'),
       xkey: 'created_at',
       ykey: ['data'],
       labels: ['Weight']
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ykey` should be `ykeys` most likely.